# Capistrano forward_agent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm trying to deploy my app from a remote git repo with capistrano. Everything was working fine till I installed ssl certificate on my server. Now the problem is when capistrano restarts the apache server the server asks for the passphrase. My question is how can I enter that passphrase from my local machine. I have enabled forward_agent by using this line but its not working.

```
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }
```

I was wondering if there is any other way to enter value on server from your local system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agent forwarding is for ssh keys, on apache restart most probably it's the sudo asking for password.

Add the deploy user to sudoers to allow apache restart, for example

```
deployer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```